# Rails Active Record Count Across Calculated Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, arel

Using the AREL / Rails [calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html) I'm trying to execute the following:

```
SELECT to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS segment, COUNT(*) AS counter 
FROM pages
GROUP BY segment
ORDER BY segment
```

I can run something like:

```
Page.order(FIELD).count(group: FIELD) 
{ a: 1, b: 4, c: 1 }
```

However, I can't get this working across calculated fields. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with this:

```
Page.count(:all, from: "(SELECT to_char(#{SEGMENT}, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  AS segment FROM pages) AS pages", group: "segment", order: "segment")
> SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, segment AS segment FROM (SELECT to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS segment FROM pages) AS pages GROUP BY segment ORDER BY segment
```